# Aspose - SVG Not shown correctly when I generate a PPTX

Tags: .net-core, svg, aspose, aspose-slides

I've got the following SVG data:

```xml
<svg id="SvgjsSvg5244" width="907.6669999999999" height="352.7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  version="1.1" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:svgjs="http://svgjs.com/svgjs"
  class="apexcharts-svg" xmlns:data="ApexChartsNS" transform="translate(0, 0)"
  style="background: transparent;">
    <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="907.6669999999999" height="352.7">
        <div class="apexcharts-legend apexcharts-align-center position-right"
          xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" bis_skin_checked="1"
          style="position: absolute; left: auto; top: 24px; right: 5px;">
            <div class="apexcharts-legend-series" rel="1" seriesname="EcoutexxxSoutienxpsychologique"
              data:collapsed="false" bis_skin_checked="1" style="margin: 2px 5px;">
                <span class="apexcharts-legend-marker" rel="1" data:collapsed="false"
                  style="background: rgb(10, 80, 110) !important; color: rgb(10, 80, 110); height: 12px; width: 12px; left: 0px; top: 0px; border-width: 0px; border-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-radius: 12px;"></span>
                <span class="apexcharts-legend-text" rel="1" i="0"
                  data:default-text="Ecoute%20-%20Soutien%20psychologique" data:collapsed="false"
                  style="color: rgb(55, 61, 63); font-size: 12px; font-weight: 400; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;">
                    Ecoute
                    - Soutien psychologique
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <style type="text/css">

            .apexcharts-legend {
            display: flex;
            overflow: auto;
            padding: 0 10px;
            }
            .apexcharts-legend.position-bottom, .apexcharts-legend.position-top {
            flex-wrap: wrap
            }
            .apexcharts-legend.position-right, .apexcharts-legend.position-left {
            flex-direction: column;
            bottom: 0;
            }
            .apexcharts-legend.position-bottom.apexcharts-align-left,
            .apexcharts-legend.position-top.apexcharts-align-left, .apexcharts-legend.position-right,
            .apexcharts-legend.position-left {
            justify-content: flex-start;
            }
            .apexcharts-legend.position-bottom.apexcharts-align-center,
            .apexcharts-legend.position-top.apexcharts-align-center {
            justify-content: center;
            }
            .apexcharts-legend.position-bottom.apexcharts-align-right,
            .apexcharts-legend.position-top.apexcharts-align-right {
            justify-content: flex-end;
            }
            .apexcharts-legend-series {
            cursor: pointer;
            line-height: normal;
            }
            .apexcharts-legend.position-bottom .apexcharts-legend-series, .apexcharts-legend.position-top
            .apexcharts-legend-series{
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            }
            .apexcharts-legend-text {
            position: relative;
            font-size: 14px;
            }
            .apexcharts-legend-text *, .apexcharts-legend-marker * {
            pointer-events: none;
            }
            .apexcharts-legend-marker {
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin-right: 3px;
            border-style: solid;
            }

            .apexcharts-legend.apexcharts-align-right .apexcharts-legend-series,
            .apexcharts-legend.apexcharts-align-left .apexcharts-legend-series{
            display: inline-block;
            }
            .apexcharts-legend-series.apexcharts-no-click {
            cursor: auto;
            }
            .apexcharts-legend .apexcharts-hidden-zero-series, .apexcharts-legend
            .apexcharts-hidden-null-series {
            display: none !important;
            }
            .apexcharts-inactive-legend {
            opacity: 0.45;
            }
        </style>
    </foreignObject>
    <g id="SvgjsG5246" class="apexcharts-inner apexcharts-graphical" transform="translate(22, 0)">
        <defs id="SvgjsDefs5245">
            <clipPath id="gridRectMaskwb7wmbsn">
                <rect id="SvgjsRect5248" width="648.6669999999999" height="352" x="-3" y="-1" rx="0" ry="0"
                  opacity="1" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" stroke-dasharray="0" fill="#fff"></rect>
            </clipPath>
            <clipPath id="gridRectMarkerMaskwb7wmbsn">
                <rect id="SvgjsRect5249" width="646.6669999999999" height="354" x="-2" y="-2" rx="0" ry="0"
                  opacity="1" stroke-width="0" stroke="none" stroke-dasharray="0" fill="#fff"></rect>
            </clipPath>
            <filter id="SvgjsFilter5257" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="200%" height="200%" x="-50%"
              y="-50%">
                <feFlood id="SvgjsFeFlood5258" flood-color="#000000" flood-opacity="0.45"
                  result="SvgjsFeFlood5258Out" in="SourceGraphic"></feFlood>
                <feComposite id="SvgjsFeComposite5259" in="SvgjsFeFlood5258Out" in2="SourceAlpha"
                  operator="in" result="SvgjsFeComposite5259Out"></feComposite>
                <feOffset id="SvgjsFeOffset5260" dx="1" dy="1" result="SvgjsFeOffset5260Out"
                  in="SvgjsFeComposite5259Out"></feOffset>
                <feGaussianBlur id="SvgjsFeGaussianBlur5261" stdDeviation="1 "
                  result="SvgjsFeGaussianBlur5261Out" in="SvgjsFeOffset5260Out"></feGaussianBlur>
                <feMerge id="SvgjsFeMerge5262" result="SvgjsFeMerge5262Out" in="SourceGraphic">
                    <feMergeNode id="SvgjsFeMergeNode5263" in="SvgjsFeGaussianBlur5261Out"></feMergeNode>
                    <feMergeNode id="SvgjsFeMergeNode5264" in="[object Arguments]"></feMergeNode>
                </feMerge>
                <feBlend id="SvgjsFeBlend5265" in="SourceGraphic" in2="SvgjsFeMerge5262Out" mode="normal"
                  result="SvgjsFeBlend5265Out"></feBlend>
            </filter>
        </defs>
        <g id="SvgjsG5250" class="apexcharts-pie">
            <g id="SvgjsG5251" transform="translate(0, 0) scale(1)">
                <g id="SvgjsG5252" class="apexcharts-slices">
                    <g id="SvgjsG5253" class="apexcharts-series apexcharts-pie-series"
                      seriesName="EcoutexxxSoutienxpsychologique" rel="1" data:realIndex="0">
                        <path id="SvgjsPath5254"
                          d="M 321.33349999999996 10.268292682926813 A 164.7317073170732 164.7317073170732 0 1 1 321.30474889339473 10.268295191934186 L 321.33349999999996 175 L 321.33349999999996 10.268292682926813"
                          fill="rgba(10,80,110,1)" fill-opacity="1" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-linecap="butt"
                          stroke-width="2" stroke-dasharray="0"
                          class="apexcharts-pie-area apexcharts-pie-slice-0" index="0" j="0" data:angle="360"
                          data:startAngle="0" data:strokeWidth="2" data:value="1"
                          data:pathOrig="M 321.33349999999996 10.268292682926813 A 164.7317073170732 164.7317073170732 0 1 1 321.30474889339473 10.268295191934186 L 321.33349999999996 175 L 321.33349999999996 10.268292682926813"
                          stroke="#ffffff"></path>
                    </g>
                    <g id="SvgjsG5255" class="apexcharts-datalabels">
                        <text id="SvgjsText5256" font-family="Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif"
                          x="321.33349999999996" y="306.78536585365856" text-anchor="middle"
                          dominant-baseline="auto" font-size="12px" font-weight="600" fill="#ffffff"
                          class="apexcharts-text apexcharts-pie-label" filter="url(#SvgjsFilter5257)"
                          style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;"
                          svgjs:data="{&quot;leading&quot;:&quot;1.3&quot;}">100.0%</text>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
        <line id="SvgjsLine5266" x1="0" y1="0" x2="642.6669999999999" y2="0" stroke="#b6b6b6"
          stroke-dasharray="0" stroke-width="1" class="apexcharts-ycrosshairs"></line>
        <line id="SvgjsLine5267" x1="0" y1="0" x2="642.6669999999999" y2="0" stroke-dasharray="0"
          stroke-width="0" class="apexcharts-ycrosshairs-hidden"></line>
    </g>
    <g id="SvgjsG5247" class="apexcharts-annotations"></g>
</svg>
```

This graphic works correctly when opened in Windows 10 as a file, but when I try to load this graphic into a generated Powerpoint (.pptx), the foreignObject is missing.

I'm importing the SVG on slide via this code :

```cs
ISvgImage svgImage = new SvgImage(config.Svg);
IPPImage ppImage = presentation.Images.AddImage(svgImage);

presentation.Slides[slideId].Shapes.AddPictureFrame(
    ShapeType.Rectangle,
    i.X,
    i.Y,
    config.Largeur != 0 ? config.Largeur : i.Width,
    config.Hauteur != 0 ? config.Hauteur : i.Height,
    ppImage
);
```

Could someone tell me what is going on? It seems like the SVG data is identical.

Thank you

Comment: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/powerpoint-app-does-not-display-svg-correctly/eb2730c6-23eb-47b9-b289-346f5d858f7e

Comment: @RobertLongson negative, not that problem :(

Comment: In what way is it different? It simply says powerpoint does not support foreignObject in SVG and that's what you're reporting too isn't it?

Comment: @RobertLongson
When i manually paste the SVG in PPT, it's ok
When aspose do that, it doesn't

Comment: When you manually paste it in, what format is it now in PPTX? SVG? DrawingML? Png?

Comment: @ToddMain, SVG !

Comment: great. extract the SVG from the OpenXML package for both methods and show code above. that may be able to help us determine the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, I was unable to reproduce the problem you described. Please check your results using the latest version of [Aspose.Slides for .NET](https://releases.aspose.com/slides/net/) if possible. If the issue persists, please share the following additional files and information:

- initial presentation file (if you used it)
- standalone code example (your code snippet contains unknown variables)
- full stack trace of the error
- OS version on which the code was executed
- .NET target platform in your app
- Aspose.Slides version you used

It would be great if you could provide the information on the Aspose.Slides forum. I work at Aspose as a Support Developer and would be happy to help you.